# Failed to create local repo in CentOS

Tags: centos, yum, repository

I'm trying to create a loca repo in Centos 6.6, so: I created the file:

```
[local]
name=Centos $releasever-$basearch
baseurl=file://var/pub/rpms
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

Then:

```
mkdir /var/pub/rpms
cp -r /media/Packages/* /var/pub/rpms/
createrepo /var/pub/rpms
[root@centos pub]# yum clean all
Complementos cargados:fastestmirror
Limpiando repositorios:base extras local updates
Limpiando todo
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
[root@centos pub]# yum repolist
Complementos cargados:fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirrors.dcarsat.com.ar
 * extras: mirrors.dcarsat.com.ar
 * updates: mirrors.dcarsat.com.ar
base                                                                                                           | 3.7 kB     00:00     
base/primary_db                                                                                                | 4.6 MB     00:04     
extras                                                                                                         | 3.4 kB     00:00     
extras/primary_db                                                                                              |  31 kB     00:00     
file://var/pub/rpms/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file://var/pub/rpms/repodata/repomd.xml
Intentando con otro espejo.
file://var/pub/rpms/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file://var/pub/rpms/repodata/repomd.xml
Intentando con otro espejo.
updates                                                                                                        | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates/primary_db                                                                                             | 3.3 MB     00:03     
id del repositorio                                              nombre del repositorio                                          estado
base                                                            CentOS-6 - Base                                                 6.518
extras                                                          CentOS-6 - Extras                                                  38
local                                                           Centos 6-x86_64                                                     0
updates                                                         CentOS-6 - Updates                                              1.155
repolist: 7.711
[root@centos pub]# ls /var/pub/rpms/repodata/repomd.xml
/var/pub/rpms/repodata/repomd.xml
```

I don't understand anything at all :(

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in baseurl:

is not:

```
baseurl=file://var/pub/rpms
```

but

```
baseurl=file:/var/pub/rpms
```

Then it worked fine.

Comment: The right way is `baseurl=file:///var/pub/rpms`. See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-setting_repository_options